# hesitate to create a condition in the radiobutton mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Good morning.

I have the following conditions in radiobutton

```
<td>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ImagensSelecionadas, new { Checked = (Model.ImagemCapaSelecionada == item.Value ? "Checked" : "") })
</td>
```

idea is as follows.
I have an image gallery, Pardo'm doing editing where I can change the cover gallery
and am using the radio button to mark the cover and tried to make the following condition, that I posted up there
that has to compare the value of the Value of ImagemCapaSelecionada item.Value and when the values ​​are equal
must to get the radio button. this condition is within a foreach loop like this:

```
@ foreach (var item in Model.ImagensDaGaleria)
```

and do not use jQuery, I have to do without Jquery ..

how do I put this condition in the html help radio button??
or what is the best way to do this?

thank you
in this case I am not getting true or false values ​​in the loop if I'm getting this imagemCapaSelecionada receives ai id ImagemCapaSelecionada querai compare the values ​​of Item.value
example

imagemcapaSelecionada | value | status
1                        5      not checked
1                        1      checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work for you...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ImagensSelecionadas, Model.ImagemCapaSelecionada == item.Value)
```

notice that the second parameter is the object value (i.e. a true or false value)

in the foreach loop...

```
@foreach(var item in Model.ImagensDaGaleria)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ImagensSelecionadas, Model.ImagemCapaSelecionada == item.Value)
}
```